# How to allocate memory for array in struct using realloc?

Tags: c, struct

Why I can't allocate memory for array `x.a` this way? Compiler says that `x.a` is not initialized in main, but I want to initialize array in function `fun`. In this function, I want to make the memory for the first element and put it in the array, make the memory for second and put it in the array etc. What should I change in this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

typedef struct {
  int *a;

} array;

void fun(int *a,int num)
{
  int i;

  for(i=0;i<num;i++)
  {
    a=(int*)realloc(a,(i+1)*sizeof(int));
    scanf("%d",(a+i));
  }
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[]) 
{
  array x;
  int i,num;

  scanf("%d",&num); //number of elements in array *a (in struct)

  fun(x.a,num);

  for(i=0;i<num;i++)
   printf("%2d",x.a[i]); //prints elements
}
```

Comment: Why not just allocate the whole space outside the loop?

Comment: `x.a` is passed to `fun` by value, so `fun` gets a copy of the pointer and the original one isn't modified. I don't know how you would fix this in C though since I code in C++. Also, `realloc()` has to copy the existing block of memory to a new location every single time (the reason it's called **re**alloc), so it's more efficient to allocate all the memory at once instead of repeatedly expanding a block of memory.

Comment: You have to set x.a to something before you can use it. The memory for x is there because that's a local variable... But x.a is a pointer to the unknown when you go to use it the first time in main.

Comment: @ScottHunter That would be the best solution, but I'm a beginner programmer and I want to practice and looking for the other solutions to one problem.

Comment: @gaga Not sure finding *bad* solutions is a good thing to practice, but to each his/her own.

Comment: It is a good practice to save the return value of `realloc` in a temporary variable in case if fails and returns NULL.  When you call: `a=(int*)realloc(a,(i+1)*sizeof(int));`, and realloc fails, you've lost the reference to the original a.  Best to call it like this: `a1 = realloc(a,(i+1)*sizeof(int));`, and then check a1 for NULL before proceeding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems. The first is that `x.a` is not set to a value before it is used. You define `x` at the start of `main`:

```
array x;
```

That creates `x` but does not put anything in it. Then you pass `x.a` to `fun` in:

```
fun(x.a,num);
```

This says to pass the **value** of `x.a` to `fun`. But `x.a` does not have a value yet, so that is wrong. (By the way, make your code readable. Put spaces after commas and semicolons, the same as in normal English text.)

Then, in `fun`, you use `a` in:

```
a=(int*)realloc(a,(i+1)*sizeof(int));
```

The first time that is executed, `a` does not have a proper value because it was passed the value from `x.a`, which was never set. `realloc` is for reallocating **existing** allocations. You have to pass it an initialized pointer value. (That includes `NULL`; you are allowed to pass it `NULL` to say you want to perform an initial allocation instead of a reallocation.)

The easiest way to fix these problems is to give `x.a` an initial value, which you can do by changing the definition of `x` to:

```
array x = { NULL };
```

The second problem is that `fun` never passes an updated value back to its caller. Your declaration of `fun` is:

```
void fun(int *a,int num)
```

This says that `fun` accepts a value that is a pointer to an int. When `fun` is called with:

```
fun(x.a,num);
```

only the value of `x.a` is passed. The actual object `x.a` is not passed, just its value. So `fun` has no way to return a new value for `x.a`. There are two ways to fix this. One is to change `fun` to accept a pointer to `x.a`:

```
void fun(int **a,int num)
```

and change the `main` routine to pass the address of `x.a`:

```
fun(&x.a,num)
```

and change every use of `a` inside `fun` to `*a`:

```
*a=(int*)realloc(*a,(i+1)*sizeof(int));
scanf("%d",(*a+i));
```

The other way is to return the new pointer as the return value of `fun`. Change the declaration of `fun` to:

```
int *fun(int *a,int num)
```

and change `main` to update `x.a` when `fun` returns it:

```
x.a = fun(x.a,num);
```

and change `fun` to return the value (do not change `a` to `*a` as above) by inserting this statement at the end:

```
return a;
```

Once that is done, your program will be largely working, but there are two more issues you ought to address:

- It is wasteful to `realloc` repeatedly when you already know the final size you want. You ought to just allocate memory once for the size you want. `realloc` is for when the size you need changes.
- `realloc` can fail. You should modify the code to handle the case when it fails and returns `NULL`.

Comment: That was really useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Just as you need to pass the *address* of `num` to have `scanf` assign to it, you'd need to pass the address of `x.a` (and change the type of the matching parameter accordingly, and the use of `a` inside of `fun`) in order to assign to it from inside `fun`.

Comment: Or you can return the new value.